# PHP - save user input into text file and displayit allowing user to reuse his inputed text

Tags: php, user-input

I have a php script that stores the content of 2 text inputs into a text file when i click "SAVE"

How can I do the folowing thing on pressing the "SAVE" button:

- step1: the text from the 2 inputs are saved in my "file1.txt"
- step2: the 2 lines of text are displayd in the same page (just like in a guestbook) but with a "RESAVE" button near the displayed lines so that the user can quickly resave what he has entered 15 minutes ago, or 5 hours ago.
  On pressing the "RESAVE" the lines showed like in a guestbook should overwrite the content of "file1.txt"
- step3: all the lines that were written by the users need to be stored in a txt file or database so that if it gets too big i can delete the oldest ones.

HTML Form:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<title></title>

<div align="center">

<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
    <B><br>
    <img src="logo_digi24.png" width="233" height="216"><br>
    <br>
Text1: </B><input name="text1" size="80" maxlength="41" type="text" placeholder="Only 41 chars allowed" class="hintTextbox" /></p>
    <B>Text2: </B><input name="text22" size="80" maxlength="73" type="text" placeholder="Only 73 chars allowed" class="hintTextbox"/></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE">

</form>


</div>
</body>
```

The PHP script that saves the content of my form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text1']) && isset($_POST['text2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['text1'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['text1'] . "\n";


    $ret = file_put_contents('file1.txt', "\xEF\xBB\xBF". $data);

    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "SAVED OK !";

        echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\"><p>GO BACK</p> </a>";

    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using a database for this. Something a long the lines of:

id, username, text1, text2

As for displaying whatever text is in "text1" and "text2" so a user can resave, you just can do something like this, create a query to pull the data out of your table based on the username.

```
<label>Text 1</label>
<input type='text' name='' value="<?php if(isset($data['text1'])) echo $data['text1']; ?>" />
```

EDIT: Why don't you save the form and validate using jQuery ?

Comment: You should use the `value` attribute of the input: `<input value="<?php echo $something; ?>" />`. The way you've written it works with `<textarea>`.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski Thanks for pointing that out! I'm still learning myself :)

Comment: It's also possible to avoid mixing up PHP and HTML by using JavaScript :)

Comment: Thank you for these answers. I don't know jquery. Could someone post an exemple related to my question ?